# Button is not getting inserted inside table row in Pug

Tags: node.js, pug, jade4j

I am trying to add the button as row element in Pug table.
But button is not getting inserted at specific row
following is the pug code

```
table
    tr#headtag
        th DishName
        th Quantity
        th Currently_Done
        th Predicted
        th 
    each order in orders
        tr
            th=order.dish.name
            th=order.numberOfQuantity
            th=order.dish.predictedValue
            th=order.dish.predictedValue
            th=button(class="btn btn-small", type="button") Slett
```

Getting 'Something failed error' in browser

Without button code is working fine.

```
table
    tr#headtag
        th DishName
        th Quantity
        th Currently_Done
        th Predicted
    each order in orders
        tr
            th=order.dish.name
            th=order.numberOfQuantity
            th=order.dish.predictedValue
            th=order.dish.predictedValue
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Remove `=` before `button` and `,` (optional) between `class` and `type` and try the following instead:

```
th
    button(class="btn btn-small" type="button") Slett
```

From the [docs](https://pugjs.org/language/code.html#buffered-code):

> Buffered code starts with `=`. It evaluates the JavaScript expression
>   and outputs the result. For security, buffered code is first HTML
>   escaped.

Therefore `th=button(class="btn btn-small", type="button") Slett` won't work.

Comment: Thanks for answer and explanation.